# unpersist() async vs sync

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Im working on a streaming application and trying to unpersist a Dataframe,so which is better to use to clear cache unpersist() --async call
or unpersist(true)--blocking call

which is better to use and why?, data size in the DF is nearly 150Gb.
And what happens internally in both cases

```
df.unpersist() //df is a cached dataframe
val inputDf: DataFrame = readFile(spec, sparkSession) //read file from S3
or anyother source
val recreateddf = inputDf.persist()
```

Spark documentation

```
DataFrame   unpersist() 
DataFrame   unpersist(boolean blocking)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but I'm curious what sort of latency you're seeing when you unpersist a 150gb DF and then rebuild it and persist it? How long does that typically take?